# What Does the Total Variation Norm Mean in the Context of Image Processing

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, total-variation

What is the notion of total variation and how is total variation norm calculated in an image?

More exactly, I want to calculate and understand the meaning of $ \left \|X \right \|_{TV} $ if $X$ is an image.

If I optimize:
$$ min_{X} \left \|X \right \|_{TV} + {other . terms} $$ how will $X$ look like and what properties would be exaggerated in image, $X$ ?

Comment: See https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/49876.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Total Variation of an image $ I $ can be calculated in one of 3 methods (See [The Meaning of the Terms Isotropic and Anisotropic in the Total Variation Framework](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/57977)):

- Anisotropic TV - $ \operatorname{TV} \left( I \right) = \sum_{x} \| \nabla I (x) \|_1 $.
- Isotropic TV - $ \operatorname{TV} \left( I \right) = \sum_{x} \| \nabla I (x) \|_2 $.
- Isotropic Squared TV - $ \operatorname{TV} \left( I \right) = \sum_{x} \| \nabla I (x) \|_2^2 $.

In practice, all yield almost the same result.

The Total Variation is a measure of how close the image is to a Piece Wise Constant function. Namely, How sparse are the changes in the gradient of the image.

You may read more at [Total Variation Denoising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_denoising).